# @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY) dependend on another field

Tags: java, xml, spring

In a Spring-MVC app in my datamodel I've two fields

`@JsonView(JsonXml_Views.List.class) private Boolean arrested;`
`@JsonView(JsonXml_Views.List.class) @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY) private Integer arrestedindex;`

The use case now is, that `arrestedindex` only should be marshalled when `arrested` is set to true. But with the annotation **@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)** `arrestedindex` also will be marshalled when `arrested` is set to false which I want to prohibit.
At the moment I absolutely have no clue how to implement this.
Anybody able to help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is `arrestedindex` not null if `arrested` is false?

Comment: Because that is the use case of the customer. We had to rewrite an old application with spring, so this unfortunatelly is legacy.

Comment: I thought this could help, but also with the JsonIcnlude.Include.CUSTOM Annotation I only can check the current value where the annotation is set, but not another value from the same class  
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-include-customized.html

Comment: The fallback option would be to provide a custom serializer that handles that level and uses the standard serializers for the rest. Have a look here for some more info: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Comment: Thank you for your input. It seems, that only this can handle my use-case.